# SQL Server : searching between dates in string data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, which stores dates as type `varchar`.

In the `SELECT` statement, I want to extract ALL values of the table, but filter the data `BETWEEN` two dates.

I have tried converting and this is the closest I have gotten. any help would be appreciated. The dates I want to filter by is called opened

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Opened BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/08/2006', 103) 
                 AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/05/2020', 103)
```

Comment: Based on the syntax, I removed the mysql tag.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  What is the issue with your query?

Comment: why would anyone store a date in a varchar column ?

Comment: In which format are the dates stored? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Maybe the format mask should be `101`, if months and days should be switched (we can't actually tell based on the query given alone).

Comment: If you must store dates into a varchar column (really really really bad idea) then at least use a format that is region independent. Read [this](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

Comment: If that is the format used in the table, it's unsuitable for range queries. You'd need `CONVERT(DATETIME, Opened, ...) BETWEEN '' AND ''`), that is, convert the column, not the values being compared. Of course this will have atrocious performance, but then that's what you get for storing dates as text.

Comment: also I suggest NOT using `between`  Read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: You should give an example of the varchar data because not all formats are compatible with convert, and we're really not supposed to guess what your data looks like.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [ask] and [mcve] for guidance on how to improve your question (and by "improve" I mean "make it more likely to get a useful answer").

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage you from using `between` with dates.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a good explanation of why, provided by Aaron Bertrand.

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.opened >= '2016-08-01' and
      t.opened < '2020-05-02'
```

If your `opened` is in the same date format, then use:

```
select t.*
from table t
where convert(date, t.opened, 103) >= '2016-08-01' and
      convert(date, t.opened, 103) < '2020-05-02'
```

However, you should fix your table so the dates are stored using the correct types, not strings.